# I could use some help figuring this out: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
  package Books;
import java.util.*;
class Book{
    private int isbn;
    private String title;
    private static int count=0;

    public Book(){
        count ++;
        }
    public void readBook(){

    int isbn=0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String temp;

        Book book = new Book(); 
        System.out.print("ISBN: ");
        temp=input.nextLine();
        book.setIsbn(Integer.parseInt(temp));

        System.out.print("title: ");
        String title = input.nextLine();
        book.setTitle(title);
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public void incrCount(){
        this.count++;
    }
    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }   
}
```

And the main one :

```
    package Books;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Ionut
 */
public class Books {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NumberFormatException{

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Book book = new Book();
        int choice;
        Book[] books = new Book[10];
        int currentIndex;
        String temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            books[i] = new Book();

        }

        while(true){
        do{
            System.out.println("Library System");
            System.out.println("       1. add book");
            System.out.println("       2. display books");
            System.out.println("       3. save to file");
            System.out.println("       4. load from file");
            System.out.println("       0. exit");
            System.out.print("choice: ");
            temp = input.nextLine();
            choice = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        }while ((choice < 0) || (choice > 4));

        switch (choice){

            case 1: //read isbn, title
                    currentIndex=book.getCount();
                    book.readBook();
                    //add current book to the array

                    books[currentIndex+1] = book;
                    book.incrCount();
                    break;
            case 2: //display array of books
                    currentIndex=book.getCount();
                    System.out.println("ISBN         Title   ");
                    for(int i=0; i< currentIndex; i++){
                    System.out.println(books[i].getIsbn()+"  "+books[i].getTitle()+"  ");
                    }
                    break;
            case 3: break;
            case 4: break;
            case 0: return ;

        }
        }//end while true
       }
}
```

In the main one I've introduced `

```
for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            books[i] = new Book();
        }
```

`
And now I no longer get the NullPointerException error but I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
run:
Library System
       1. add book
       2. display books
       3. save to file
       4. load from file
       0. exit
choice: 1
ISBN: 1
title: 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
    at Books.Books.main(Books.java:49)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Any help is well apreciated.
I dont understand why i get this error, I just initialized the array why would it go out of bounds ?

Comment: Somewhere you try to access `books[12]`. That's not correct, 'cause your array is 10 long. Did you try to debug this code? What's your 49th line in Books.java?

Comment: The 49th line is : books[currentIndex+1] = book; My program "dies" at the end of case 1 when he meets that line.

Comment: Ok. So `currentIndex` is gonna be 11. The `count` in you `Book` class says, that how many times it was read? How it comes to index the array? Did you try to debug this code? If not, try to debug it! Place there a breakpoint, and see the value of `currentIndex`!

Comment: Relevant: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: When I press the Debug button i get this : debug:
Error: Could not find or load main class books.Books
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds).

Comment: Should be Books.Books, check you main class name in your run configuration. Use the wizard to select it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the switch 1, cus it's refering to an out of bounds thanks to the ++. You never specified it shouldnt add more if it´s on the last book of the array.

Ah yeah, you could use the ArrayList as the guy here said. I believe with that you can just do      arraylist.add(book);    or whatever, arraylists are created without a max arent they?